# Laravel eloquent query not updating checkbox input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Why does the following hard coded eloquent query work:

```
Auth::user()->update(['text_only_email' => true ]);
```

But when the data comes via a form checkbox input it always updates as false even when the input is true ?

```
$data['text_only_email'] = $request->input('text_only_email', false);
Auth::user()->update($data);
```

See results from die and dump to prove the incoming value is true:

```
$data['text_only_email'] = $request->input('text_only_email', false);

dd($data);
```

Results of dump:

```
array:1 [▼
  "text_only_email" => "true"
]
```

*** UPDATE ***

I've added the following mutator to my User model to cast as boolean but it still doesnt work. Is my casting a string to boolean correct?

```
public function setTextOnlyEmailAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['text_only_email'] = (bool)($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of **test_only_email** that you're getting in the request is a string, not a boolean. Convert it first to a boolean true/false value and then pass to **update()**.

Comment: I've added the following mutator to my user model to cast as boolean but it still doesnt work - see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Your mutator will always return true because "true" and "false" returns true when casted to boolean, both are strings with more than zero characters. You should do something like this:

```
public function setTextOnlyEmailAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['text_only_email'] = $value == 'true' ? true : 
false;
}
```